# Use stored procedure so that the output can be saved in a file or as an output parameter

Tags: sql-server, xml, bcp

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have a stored procedure that returns XML data. I want to use the stored procedure using `bcp' and return the output to an XML file or call the stored procedure within another stored procedure and store the data as an XML variable.

To save it to a file the stored procedure so not have an OUTPUT parameter and returns the data as XML.

This works

```
SET @CopyXmlCmd = 'bcp "EXEC CreateXMLFileOfDatabase " queryout "' + @FileAndPath + '" -T -w -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME()
EXEC master..XP_CMDSHELL @CopyXmlCmd
```

The stored procedure, `CreateXMLFileOfDatabase` has no output or input parameters.  But I need to also have this stored procedure work for this:

```
DECLARE @XmlTargetDB XML;
EXEC CreateXMLFileOfDatabase @ResultDB = @XmlTargetDB
```

The signature for this version of the stored procedure is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateXMLFileOfDatabase] @ResultDB XML OUTPUT
```

Can I use `bcp` using a stored procedure that has an output parameter and store the results to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

I assume, that the final command in your SP is `SELECT TheXml;`

In this case you can declare a fitting table and insert the result:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(MyXMLColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl(MyXMLColumn)
EXEC YourProcedure;
```

--From this table you can set the value to an XML variable:

```
DECLARE @ResultXML XML;
SELECT @ResultXML=MyXMLColumn FROM @tbl;
```

## UPDATE: Example

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestOutputXML
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST('<root>test</root>' AS XML) AS Test
END
GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(MyResult XML);

INSERT INTO @tbl(MyResult)
EXEC dbo.TestOutputXML;

DECLARE @MyXMLVariable XML=(SELECT TOP 1 MyResult FROM @tbl);

SELECT @MyXMLVariable;
GO

DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TestOutputXML;
```

Comment: The final command is SELECT xmlVariable.  But the problem is that I need this stored procedure to be called using `bcp` to be saved to a file AND called from another stored procedure and the output has to be assigned to a XML variable.  So, when the stored procedure does not have an `OUTPUT` parameter it works fine with `bcp` and saved to a file.  But this version will not work when called from a stored procedure because the xml output has to have an `OUTPUT` parameter.  Stored procedures can only return int.

Comment: Do I have to have 2 versions of this stored procedure?  One with an OUTPUT parameter and one that does not so that the results can be sent to a file when used with `bcp`

Comment: @GloriaSantin, no, the way I showed you would not need two versions... It was better - if possible for you - to put *reading* issues in (inline table valued) functions rather than in SPs, but this should work for you for both needs... In general: If you know the exact structure of your SP's last `SELECT` you can create a fitting table and insert this there. In your case this should be a *one-column-one-row result*...

Comment: So I don't need an output parameter?

Comment: But I need the return value to be in the form of an xml file.

Comment: @GloriaSantin, sorry, but I do not understand *But I need the return value to be in the form of an xml file*... The approach I show you puts the XML into the variable `@MyXMLVariable`. I thought - from your code lines with `DECLARE` - that it is this what you need... What is *the form of an xml file*?

Comment: I am just confused by the `@tbl` variable.  So by saving the xml output to the table variable and then assigning the select to the xml variable this replaces the `output` parameter...correct?

Comment: @GloriaSantin, yes, that's it... Just try it ;-) Many people use SPs for *reading* data. I don't know why... The only chance to continue with the resultset of a SP is to insert it into a fitting table. It was so much easier to reach the same with an *inline TVF*...

Comment: @GloriaSantin Hi, I just reduced my example to the lines really needed...

Comment: Wow!  That worked like a charm!  Thanks for hanging with me!